# Groovy Collections: count weirdness with Strings

Tags: collections, groovy

I am trying to count string values in a member of an object. I have tried three ways, but only one works. I am fine with the one that works, but I can't understand why the others fail. Here's the code:

```
void testCount() {
    TestObj a = new TestObj()
    TestObj b = new TestObj()
    TestObj c = new TestObj()
    a.s = "one"
    b.s = "two"
    c.s = "two"

    def list = [a, b, c]

    def count = 0
    list.each{
        if (it.s.equals("two"))
            count++
    }
    assertTrue("each test failed", count == 2)
    assertTrue("collectAll test failed", list.collectAll{ it.s.equals("two")}.size() == 2)
    assertTrue("count test failed", list.count{ it.s.equals("two")} == 2)        
}
```

I would expect the Closures passed to collectAll and count to do the same thing I'm doing in my each method. But in the case of collectAll it returns all 3 of the objects and in the case of count it always returns 0.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[collectAll](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) is [recursively](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectNested%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) going through your list, and returning a boolean (as that is what your closure returns for each element in the List)...

So, you get `[ false, true, true ]`, which has 3 elements...

For `count`,

```
list.count{ it.s == "two" }
```

Returns `2` (as expected)

btw: you can do `it.s == 'two'` in groovy.. no need for all the `.equals( "two" )`

#### Edit...  Example for count:

```
class TestObj {
  String s
}

list = [ new TestObj( s:'one' ), new TestObj( s:'two' ), new TestObj( s:'two' ) ]

println( list.count { it.s == 'two' } )
```

Prints `2` for me...

#### edit 2

Found the cause (from comment below), [count didn't accept a closure](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2898) as a parameter till 1.8 so you'll be calling the [object version](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#count%28java.lang.Object%29) which will tell you how many times an instance of the closure exists in the list (which is none, as it says)

Comment: Thanks. The collectAll was a bogus test for sure. But I'm not getting love from list.count{ it.s == "two" }. It still returns 0.

Comment: I verified that this is working for others. Must be something about my environment.  Thanks Tim for the quick reply.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is actually in groovy 1.7.x. The person on my end who has it working is using groovy 1.8.

Comment: Ahhhhh yeah, [count didn't accept a closure](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2898) as a parameter till 1.8 so you'll be calling the [object version](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#count(java.lang.Object)) which will tell you how many times the closure exists in the list (which is none, as it says)